# How do I do get-itemproperty with an added filter?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

I basically want this to work.

```
invoke-command -ComputerName Server {Get-ItemProperty -Path 'C:\\windows'-Filter *.txt  } |  sort-object lastwritetime | FT

invoke-command -ComputerName Server {Get-ItemProperty -Path 'C:\\windows'-exclude *.log  } |  sort-object lastwritetime | FT
```

For some reason I cannot search for the location and file type at the same time.

Could somebody help?

Comment: What should be the expected result of these queries? And why you're using a double backslash?

Comment: the cmdlet DOES NOT do what you seem to think. [*grin*] from the help >>> `Gets the properties of a specified item.` <<< it gets ONE item. plus, your `-Filter` is being applied to the directory name. if you want the items INSIDE a directory, use `Get-ChildItem` instead.

Comment: Thank you for this;so if i was to do get-childitem and run the below                                                 invoke-command -ComputerName server {Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\\analyst\data\ntx' -Recurse } | Where-Object {$_.name  -Like "*NTX"} |  sort-object lastwritetime | FT                  how would i then just filter this to the most recent file in this folder,instead of more than one and then after doing that,how would i go about getting the input for the output for many machines,as i would like to get the last time this file has been written to the directory for many machines?

Comment: get rid of `| FT` and do `Sort-Object lastwritetime | Select-Object -Last 1`. BTW. Putting code in a comment makes it unreadable. If you have extra information, [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61662186/edit) your question and put it in there as [Formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) code.